# How do I review proposed changes on Documentation BETA?

Tags: bug, status-declined, documentation, review-queues, documentation-review

Occasionally, I try to participate on Stack Overflow by reviewing first posts, suggested edits and late answers. Over the course of time, I gained experience and know how to handle the review pages.

However, I'm lost in the **Documentation: Proposed Changes** section.

When a review is available and gets assigned to me, I can see the article in question and I can also see the suggested changes. But there are no buttons—as on the other review pages—I could click to perform an action.

The FAQ for Documentation BETA states that a reviewer can vote on changes, that four votes are required to grant or deny a change and that a user has 1-4 votes depending on his reputation.

[image: Review proposed changes on Documentation BETA]

So why don't I see any vote buttons? Is this a bug maybe; icons in the new navigation bar keep flickering. I'm using Opera 12.18 on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Yup, that's a client bug. Here's how I see the queue in Safari:

[image: Approve, Reject, Skip. Red freehand circle.]

Comment: All right, thanks. I'd assume that the Documentation reviews are based on similar code as the other reviews and there should not be much difference displaying the buttons.

Answer (score 0):

The buttons are defined with `<button>` tags. They're in the HTML on the page, but the browser doesn't render them correctly unless a z-index value is explicitly specified in CSS. I have no idea why this is only happening to *some* buttons, or why some (but not all) `<li>` elements in the top bar have similar issues.

All blame signs point to "Opera 12.18", though. Released about a year ago, it looks to me like it's not even really supported/developed further by Opera itself. We [officially support](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56161/which-browsers-are-officially-supported-and-what-else-do-i-need) "the last two versions of the browsers that we see the vast majority of our visitors actually use". Opera (all versions) accounts for a rather small % of visitors, so I don't think making a browser-specific style change makes sense here:

> [image]

If Opera 12.18 supports custom stylesheets, you should be able to put a z-index on buttons. It looks like they're working fine so long as they're actually rendered in the correct place. I also recommend upgrading to a more modern browser if at all possible since various features of the site will very likely start or continue breaking as time goes on.